# Is there a way to send a mongodump over sftp without using diskspace?

Tags: mongodb

Problem

We have a mongo database (on ubuntu server) we need to migrate. However the old server has not enough disk space to store `mongodump`. Can we send it to another computer skipping local storage? Receiving end is either a Mac or another ubuntu server.

Comment: In the manual, I see a "--out -" option to write on screen. Then, pipe it to ssh and go on network. https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can designate a old server using the [--host option in mongodump][1] on your new / separate computer with the available disk space. This simply initiates the dump from the new machine and stores it there. In MongoDB 3.2 the tools offer the ability to use [standard output][2], in this case if you wanted to initiate the dump on the new machine and then also pipe to mongorestore on that machine you could directly import the data to the new machine without using disk. If your old server mongod is relatively recent version 2.6+ I don't believe there will be any issues using the 3.2 version tools (mongodump and mongorestore). If you want to reduce space utilisation you could consider using the WiredTiger storage engine, if you are not already using it.

In this approach you won't need to use sftp.